For CHSH game, why does the mathematica program gives 75% as the best winning rate when sharing 2 EPR pairs?
In the CHSH game , the optimal quantum winning rate should be approximately 85% when Alice and Bob share the EPR states and this winning rate holds the same when they share arbitrarily many EPR states. The optimal strategy is (locally  isomorphic to) acting on only one EPR.  I write a mathematica program searching for the best winning rate when sharing two EPR pairs, the code is
matrixA = {{1}, {0}, {0}, {1}};
matrixB = KroneckerProduct[matrixA, matrixA];
rho = (1/4)* matrixB . Transpose[matrixB];
A0 = Array[a0, {4, 4}];
B0 = Array[b0, {4, 4}];
A1 = Array[a1, {4, 4}];
B1 = Array[b1, {4, 4}];
D00 = KroneckerProduct[A0, B0];
D01 = KroneckerProduct[A0, B1];
D10 = KroneckerProduct[A1, B0];
D11 = KroneckerProduct[A1, B1];
constraints = {VectorGreaterEqual[{A0 + IdentityMatrix[4], 
     0}, {"SemidefiniteCone", 4}], 
   VectorGreaterEqual[{IdentityMatrix[4] - A0, 
     0}, {"SemidefiniteCone", 4}],
   VectorGreaterEqual[{IdentityMatrix[4] + B0, 
     0}, {"SemidefiniteCone", 4}],
   VectorGreaterEqual[{IdentityMatrix[4] - B0, 
     0}, {"SemidefiniteCone", 4}],
   VectorGreaterEqual[{IdentityMatrix[4] + A1, 
     0}, {"SemidefiniteCone", 4}],
   VectorGreaterEqual[{IdentityMatrix[4] - A1, 
     0}, {"SemidefiniteCone", 4}],
   VectorGreaterEqual[{IdentityMatrix[4] + B1, 
     0}, {"SemidefiniteCone", 4}],
   VectorGreaterEqual[{IdentityMatrix[4] - B1, 
     0}, {"SemidefiniteCone", 4}]};
objective = 0.5 + 1/8*(Tr[rho . (D00 + D01 + D10 - D11)]);
maximizeResult = 
     NMaximize[{objective, constraints}, Flatten[{A0, B0, A1, B1}], 
     WorkingPrecision -> 10, Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"] // 
    Chop;;
maximizeResult

For $-I \preceq A_0,B_0,A_1,B_1\preceq I$, the winning rate is $0.5+1/8Tr((A_0\otimes B_0+ A_0\otimes B_1+A_1\otimes B_0-A_1\otimes B_1)\rho)$. But the above program gives an output of 0.7500005245, which is the best winning value for classical case.
I also tried the case Alice and Bob share one EPR, the code is
A0 = Array[a0, {2, 2}];
B0 = Array[b0, {2, 2}];
A1 = Array[a1, {2, 2}];
B1 = Array[b1, {2, 2}];
rho = {{1/2, 0, 0, 1/2}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {1/2, 0, 0, 1/2}};

D00 = KroneckerProduct[A0, B0];
D01 = KroneckerProduct[A0, B1];
D10 = KroneckerProduct[A1, B0];
D11 = KroneckerProduct[A1, B1];
constraints = {VectorGreaterEqual[{A0 + IdentityMatrix[2], 
     0}, {"SemidefiniteCone", 2}], 
   VectorGreaterEqual[{IdentityMatrix[2] - A0, 
     0}, {"SemidefiniteCone", 2}],
   VectorGreaterEqual[{IdentityMatrix[2] + B0, 
     0}, {"SemidefiniteCone", 2}],
   VectorGreaterEqual[{IdentityMatrix[2] - B0, 
     0}, {"SemidefiniteCone", 2}],
   VectorGreaterEqual[{IdentityMatrix[2] + A1, 
     0}, {"SemidefiniteCone", 2}],
   VectorGreaterEqual[{IdentityMatrix[2] - A1, 
     0}, {"SemidefiniteCone", 2}],
   VectorGreaterEqual[{IdentityMatrix[2] + B1, 
     0}, {"SemidefiniteCone", 2}],
   VectorGreaterEqual[{IdentityMatrix[2] - B1, 
     0}, {"SemidefiniteCone", 2}]};
objective = 0.5 + 1/8*(Tr[rho . (D00 + D01 + D10 - D11)]);
maximizeResult = 
    NMaximize[{objective, constraints}, Flatten[{A0, B0, A1, B1}], 
   Method -> "DifferentialEvolution", WorkingPrecision -> 10];
maximizeResult

This time the code output 0.8535490666 which is the known best winning rate. So why it is failed when Alice and Bob share 2 EPR states?

I'm not saying this is your problem, but I haven't always had the greatest success using semidefinite programming in Mathematica - I've seen it give odd answers. While I use Mathematica for a lot of stuff, I use other systems for semidefinite programming (e.g. matlab with the MOSEK solver).

I think the problem you're having is with your tensor product structure. If you label the qubits 1 to 4, then your A measurements are on qubits 1 and 2, while your B measurements are on qubits 3 and 4. However, you have two Bell pairs: one shared between 1 and 2, and one shared between 3 and 4. There is no entanglement shared between Alice and Bob, so you can't beat the classical bound. Instead, you want to create a Bell pair between 1 and 3, and another between 2 and 4.
